# Drupal Relation Visualization

Tags: drupal, reference, visualization, relation

what is the best way to visualize relationships of contents (like a graph) in Drupal? Is there any tutorial or a good instruction? I just found https://www.drupal.org/node/1392374 but it doesn't work.  I just got a grey graphic instead of the graph.

Thank you very very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What graphing engine are you using?